# how can i get the annotation value declared from throw clause in JDK 8?

Tags: java, java-8, annotations

I defined a business exception(extend runtime exception) which can be thrown by multiple situation to provide details infomation.

```java
/**
 * business exception
 */
public class BusinessException extends RuntimeException {
    private String code;
    private String msg;

    public BusinessException(String code) {
        super(code);
        this.code = code;
        this.msg = "";
    }

    public BusinessException(String code, String errorMessage) {
        super(code + " " + errorMessage);
        this.code = code;
        this.msg = errorMessage;
    }
}
```

here is a example

```java
//if a excepted error occured
throws new BusinessException(code);
```

As time passed, I found this class only define two field, and I want to provide more infomation within exceptions, and do not want to change the original exception class(simple add a another field named 'more' is another solution, but I don't want to do this).

I found JDK 8 has declared ElementType.TYPE_USE which providing more possibility in handle java annotations.so I'm trying to take advantage of this new feature.

I wrote code like this.

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)
public @interface Details {
    String more() default "";

}
```

```java
//if a excepted error occured, provide more infomation with annotations
throw @Details(more="detail msgs") new BusinessException(code);
```

I try to find a way to get annotion value from thrown clause in reflection api, but found this impossible. I am trapped with this. anyone can help me?best thankful.

Comment: Why don't you want to add an additional field? I don't think it will break anything (?) - it's like the most natural thing to do in this situation!

Comment: Quite agree with you. since jdk provided this new feature, i'm just curious why I could not get the annotation value in runtime.?I could easily get the exact annotation value from parameter, return value, even from fields throgh java reflection api. Why can't I do this with throwing clause? The java development team have any consideration about this?I searched JDK relection api from JDK 8 to the newest 18, can't found any description about this.

Comment: The reflection API doesn't give you any way to access the *bodies* of methods. The annotation is in the class file though, so you can always read that with ASM or whatever bytecode reader.

Comment: Get that. I think that's the same reason I can't access the annotation value from local variable too. ASM is definitely another solution. tks a lot.